# How to compute the similarity between two arrays?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose there are two arrays (They have the same length), I want to give a quantitative description about the similarity between them. Is there any way to achieve that? I define a formula like this, but how to calculate it?
$$
\min_{1\le i\le n,1\le j\le n}(A_i-B_j)^2
$$

Comment: I think this question needs more background on "similarity between predicted data and observed data," mentioned in your comment below. Otherwise it makes not much sense.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you are right. It just occurred to me when I was reviewing what I have learned on my course "Introduction to Bayesian Statistics". Therefore, there is not much background.

Answer (score 1):

Some standard distances are
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(A_i-B_i)^2\\
\sum_{i=1}^n|A_i-B_i|\\
\max_i|A_i-B_i|$$
But they are only useful if the order matters in each array.

Comment: Yes. Actually my goal is to measure the similarity between two groups and the similarity should not be affected by the order. For example, I build a model with some observed data, and then I can use this model to predict new data. Now, I want to decide if this model is valid depending on the similarity between predicted data and observed data. Is there any method?

Comment: That is a big part of statistics.  Perhaps look up 'Student's t test'